# What day is it? or What day is it on?

Tags: grammar

Are "what day is it?" and "what day is it on?" both correct? Or is one more correct than the other? Or is one correct/formal and the other informal?

What would you use in these examples and why:

Example 1

- Hi, Daniel. Is Peter's concert tonight?
- No, it's at the weekend.
- What day is it?/What day is it on?
- It's on Saturday.

Example 2

- What day is Christmas this year?/What day is Christmas on this year?
- It's on a Saturday.

Answer (score 2):

Both are understood.

Consider the question:
**What day is it?** *(today being implied)*

It's Monday *(well, here it is!)*

Change the subject it = Christmas

What day is Christmas this year? has the meaning of a day of the week (as opposed to date). If you think about it. 
Christmas is on a Saturday this year. (The "a Saturday" meaning the generic Saturday. Like- this is a dog)

When is his concert?
It's on Saturday. 
(Who's dog is this? Our dog)

Looking at this there are errors in the question.

A correction:

> Example 1
>
> Hi, Daniel. Is Peter's concert tonight?
>
> No, it's at the weekend.

*No, it's **at** the weekend. (it's **at 'a venue'**)*

*No, it's **on** the weekend.*

> What day is it?/What day is it on?

***Which day?*** or
*Which day is it?* or
*Which day is it on?*

> It's on Saturday.

Asking **What day is Christmas on this year?** is formal, yes.

Comment: Hey! You're back! Good to see you :) (wish we had private messaging)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I rage quit [se] lol and am back..  I only have one account on a suspension lol I am trying to behave myself.. good to see you and thnx for remembering me.. I just posted a new Q and am not sure about tags etc..

Comment: Welcome back. I saw your Q, the tags are fine. Promote Pets if that's your thing. I'm more a man gal myself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA can I promote [pets.se] lol